# MongoDB sharding working on only one instace

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have created three mongodb instances on localhost with different port like

```
mongod.exe --config C:\MongoDB2.6\mongod.cfg

mongod.exe --config D:\MongoDB2.6\mongodinst1.cfg

mongod.exe --config E:\MongoDB2.6\mongodinst2.cfg
```

These 3 are getting instantiated successfully (running on port 2021,2022,2023).
Now I am using the mongos command for clustering for these three instance and my command is like this

```
mongos.exe --configdb 127.0.0.1:2021,127.0.0.1:2022,127.0.0.1:2023
```

It is syncing the  three mongodb instances successfully. now I am connecting to the mongos instance on port 27017 and creating the shard

```
 sh.addShard("127.0.0.1:2021")
 sh.addShard("127.0.0.1:2022")
 sh.addShard("127.0.0.1:2023")
```

This process is also successful. After this on the mongos instance (27017), I am creating one db(myshard) and collection(mycoll).

Now I insert data into this collection:

```
db.myshard.insert([
...
{
   title: 'NoSQL Database', 
   description: 'NoSQL database doesn',
   by: 'tutorials point',
   url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   likes: 20, 
   comments: [  
      {
         user:'user1',
         message: 'My first comment',
         dateCreated: new Date(2013,11,10,2,35),
         like: 0 
      }
   ]
},
...
])
```

Now it is reflecting the these values to me on my one of the instances running on port 2021 but not on others instance like 2022 and 2023 port.

I am new to mongodb and not understanding why it is happening like this. Could someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question: You have created a sharded environment successfully, and are now inserting data into the cluster via the `mongos` shell. The problem you are describing sounds like you are trying to manually check the actual `mongod` instances (shards) for the documents you have inserted - is this correct?

Comment: yes i am manually checking all the 3 instace for the data but it reflecting the db which i have created on mongos instance on only one of the three instance on which mongodb is running. @Lix

Comment: StackOverlfow is a "programming Q&A Forum". If you have questions related to database administration and configuration the go and ask them on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. That goes double for those who persist in trying to answer these questions here.

Comment: @NeilLunn - you are correct in saying that perhaps dba.SE is a better fit for database related questions, but just because this post would be on-topic for dba.SE doesn't mean that it's inherently off-topic for [so]. Mongo is a tool often used by programmers and hence *is* on-topic IMO.

Comment: @Lix Yes it does mean that I am correct ( enjoy the flood of upvotes just because I contradicted you, it's a pattern but it does not mean you are correct ). The question clearly shows replica set nodes on other ports than `27017` which means that `mongos` is running on that default port and being connected to by all the content. Which also makes your assumed answer invlaid ( despite someone who did not really read it up-voting it ). So there it is. While I also aggree many "Mongo" and "NoSQL" questions have "blurred lines" this is not one of them.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I must be missing something then... I can't "clearly" see replica set nodes at all. All I can see is 3 mongod nodes, each on a different port (because it's a local cluster). I just see a local sharded cluster. Could you please expand on why you feel my answer is not helpful/invalid?

Comment: @Lix Sorry shards and not replica-set. Question is off topic. Same people I keep berating for answering off-topic questions are going to support you anyway so enjoy the boon. Someone might argue that this will "migrate" to the correct site but that's never going to happen because no-one cares. Not even the people maintaining the site apparently. I only ask for consistency and it never happens. Hopefully enough people hate to get you upvoted to 20. That would be cool.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I share your frustration about people hurrying to answer off-topic questions and often find myself making comments such as: "please don't encourage this type of behavior by supplying answers". Regarding this specific post I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. We *can* however agree that there might be a better place to post this question however, in it's current state (and location), I still firmly believe that this artifact we have created has great potential to assist future visitors and as such I feel it retains it's value.

Comment: @Lix Whatever. I'm really not into arguments and I'm really over the attitude of moderators and other users here who should be more more community minded than the actions they exhibit. I'm not changing my line and that is my opinion ( even thought it is likely to be removed for exactly what I mentioned earlier ). Congrats on the upvotes and the accept, but even though how you answered it, I'm sure the actual problem was seen to be a server issue based on the information provided. Doesn't matter. Write something on topic and correct and I'm the first person to boost your effectiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what is happening here is that the sharded cluster is deciding which shard to use according to your shard key (defaults to `_id`). You don't necessarily know ahead of time which shard is going to be used and where exactly the document will be stored.

This "issue" is handled by mongos and the config servers. The config servers hold meta information about your cluster, for example, where the data is located within your sharded cluster.

In order to take advantage of the sharding mechanism, **all of your queries should be executed on the `mongos` shell**. This is the only method that you can use to extract any data from anyone of your shards. The mongos shell will query your databases and collections according the meta information that your config servers contains.

Comment: It means mongos and config server will decide to create the db on any instance and collections ? it is not necessary that mongos instance will put my collection data on all the mongodb instance which are running ?

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh - true. I think you are confusing a sharded cluster with a replica set. A replica set will actually create a mirror copy of your cluster including all config/mongod instances. A sharded cluster is just a way to split your data across a number of mongod instances.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using your config servers as the data-bearing nodes. You should not do this. Create additional mongod instances that are not config servers and add those as shards from mongos. See [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).